# Check if an item exists without an error if it doesn't exist

Tags: powershell

I'd like to use PowerShell to check whether an IIS Web Application exists (or potentially some other kind of item). I can do this with `Get-Item`, but that reports an error if the item doesn't exist, which is misleading to the user running the script - it looks like something went wrong when actually everything is fine.

How do I do this without an error?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use the command ... `get-item blah -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

[image]

Comment: `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` can be shortened to `-ea si`, `dir app_offline.htm -ea si | del`

Comment: For the sake of readability, I wouldn't abbreviate in a script (per the question).

Comment: Strictly speaking this isn't an answer to the question, the Test-Path answer below is an actual check

Answer (score 60):

The cmdlet `Test-Path` is specifically designed for this, it determines whether items of a path exist. It returns a Boolean value and does not generate an error.

The cmdlet `Get-Item` (and similar) can be used, too, but not directly. One way is already proposed: use `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`. It might be important to know that in fact it still generates an error; it just does not show it. Check the error collection `$Error` after the command, the error is there.

---

Just for information

There is a funny way to avoid this error (it also works with some other cmdlets like `Get-Process` that do not have a `Test-Path` alternative). Suppose we are about to check existence of an item "MyApp.exe" (or a process "MyProcess"). Then these commands return nothing on missing targets and at the same time they generate no errors:

```
Get-Item "[M]yApp.exe"
Get-Process "[M]yProcess"
```

These cmdlets do not generate errors for wildcard targets. And we use these funny wildcards that actually match single items.

Comment: This would be my approach! Also worth noting, is that you can echo out the good finds with this method, and not get red errors for files that do not exist. if (Test-path $Test){write-host $Test}
By default, an item that doesn't exists will not have an event, so nothing is displayed, or the false is suppressed.

Comment: This is the best approach to the question