# PowerShell count not working for single matches

Tags: powershell

I'm running the following PowerShell code to retrieve matches in my inbox and wondering why my filter isn't working for instances where there's only a single match. Here's the code to find and filter the matches;

```
 Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" | out-null 
 $olFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders" -as [type]  
 $outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application 
 $namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI") 
 $inbox = $namespace.getDefaultFolder($olFolders::olFolderInBox) 
 $filter = (%{$inbox.items | Where {$_.SenderName -match ‘JoeUser’ -and
 $_.UnRead -eq $true}})
```

...and when I ask for a count of matches by running **$filter.count**, I get the correct answer AS LONG AS there is more than one match. So, for scenarios where there is only a single, matching message in my inbox, the **$filter.count** doesn't return anything and teh subsequent code fails to process on the message- and I know that the match picked up the matching message because I can view it from **$filter**

Can anyone figure out why this count doesn't work on a single match from $filter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A variable doesn't get cast as an array when only one value is returned by the right hand side of the assignment.

There are a bunch of previous questions dealing with this:

- [How can I force Powershell to return an array when a call only returns one object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107428/how-can-i-force-powershell-to-return-an-array-when-a-call-only-returns-one-objec)
- [How to count objects in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526285/how-to-count-objects-in-powershell)
- [Count length of array and return 1 if it only contains one element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580260/count-length-of-array-and-return-1-if-it-only-contains-one-element)
- [How to Return a Pretty Zero Value with the Count Property from Get-Process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629087/how-to-return-a-pretty-zero-value-with-the-count-property-from-get-process)

Can be fixed by adding '@' as follows:

```
$filter = @(%{$inbox.items | Where {$_.SenderName -match ‘JoeUser’ -and $_.UnRead -eq $true}})
```

Apparently, this behavior changes in PowerShell v3: http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=1235149

Comment: Thanks! That little ampersand worked as you stated! Evidently that changed my $filter from a string to an array and now my $filter.count correctly shows a value of 1. 

Apologies for the redundant question.

Answer (score 6):

Beside what others suggest you can always get correct answer with `$filter | measure | % count`